# Sublime Text 2 Wants to Only Build Using Java

Tags: build, sublimetext2

For some reason, if I try to run and build a .py .cpp .tex or etc and I try to build any file it tries to run java and returns an error like this:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'javac', u'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\evolve1\\case0\\herp.cpp']]
[dir:  C:\Users\name\Documents\evolve1\case0]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime Alternative\QTSystem;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Python27\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Avogadro\bin]
[Finished]
```

This is weird on multiple levels, but I'm primarily concerned with getting it to stop building with Java (which I never use anyways) and im a tad confused about why its looking in that particular dir in the third line considering I never even ran code in there.

Answer (score 1):

Select **`Tools -> Build System -> Automatic`**, and Sublime should pick the correct build system depending on the syntax of the source file. For example, when editing a `.py` file, after saving and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, you should build with Python. If for some reason that doesn't work, just select your desired build system before you build.